# Using where search clause after select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and I'm adding some updates to already existing app. I need to add filtering by search word and I'm trying to use `where` with `ILIKE` to do that but due to the original code is written. the original code uses Model.select to get the records and when i try to chain where with the `ILIKE` clause to that it still returns the whole array not filtered.

```
  date_format = get_js_date_format_by_id(@account.date_format_id)
  sort_format = "#{params[:sort_item] || "date"} #{params[:sort_order] || "asc"}"

  @expenses = Expense.select("expenses.*, to_char(expenses.date, '#{date_format}') as formatted_date,
      to_char(
        CASE
          WHEN expense_categories.is_calculated = true then expenses.amount * expense_categories.unit_cost
          ELSE expenses.amount
        END, 'FM999999990.00') as total,
        CASE
        WHEN expense_categories.is_calculated = true then expense_categories.unit_name
          ELSE null
          END as unit_name,
        '' as images_list,
       users.name as user_name, expense_categories.name as category_name, projects.name as project_name, clients.name as client_name")
       .joins(:user, :project, :expense_category, :client)

  if params[:query]
    @expenses.includes(:user).where('users.name ILIKE :query', { query: "%#{params[:query]}%"}).references(:users)
  end
  @expenses.where(conditions)
  .order(sort_format)

  if params[:page]
    @expenses = @expenses.page(params[:page]).per(params[:per_page])
  end


  @expenses
```

I'm adding the filtering part starting at `if params[:query]` the rest is the original code. any help would be appreciated to pin pointing the problem. 
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't modify the current `@expenses` scope with:

```rb
  if params[:query]
    @expenses.includes(:user).where('users.name ILIKE :query', { query: "%#{params[:query]}%"}).references(:users)
  end
```

This line returns the new scope you want, but you are not saving it anywhere. Following code should work:

```rb
  if params[:query]
    @expenses = @expenses.includes(:user).where('users.name ILIKE :query', { query: "%#{params[:query]}%"}).references(:users)
  end
```

*Note: same thing applies for the sorting under the `params[:query]` condition.*

Comment: Hi @edariedl thank you for the answer. I modified the code as you said and I got this error **#<NoMethodError: undefined method 'formatted_date' for #<Expense:0xb026998>>** this is coming from the serializer as we sent the  `formatted_date` attribute back to the user and it can't be found after i changed the code as you suggested

Comment: The `formatted_date` is coming from the select statement attached in the original question.

Comment: Can you look at the log how the generated SQL looks like?

Comment: Sorry  @edariedl,  I missed the notifications for this. here is the generated SQL 
https://textuploader.com/10vjk